# How do I make the default Google Chrome link on the Windows 8 Start Screen open Chrome in the desktop?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8

By default, a fresh install of Google Chrome will place an entry on the Start Screen that when clicked will open the Modern UI/Metro version of Chrome. This is frustrating, as I want to have it open in my desktop. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah, I tracked it down. Open up regedit and set all of these keys to empty:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command\DelegateExecute

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Chrome\.exe\shell\open\command\DelegateExecute

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Chrome\.exe\shell\opennewwindow\command\DelegateExecute

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Chrome\.exe\shell\run\command\DelegateExecute
```

After you close regedit, when you go to open Chrome from the start screen it will open in your desktop.

Comment: [Source](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/35641-Disable-Chrome-Metro-in-Windows-8?p=645663&viewfull=1#post645663)